# Real time load testing with Jmeter webdriver sampler

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

I need to load test a mendix application .
The requirement is - 10 users should be able to perform file upload function simultaneously .
But the test should be like real life situation where 10 users will use 10 different machines, accounts and browsers. Basically no shared resources.
I have written Jmeter webdriver sampler and trying to setup on multiple VMs in distributed way.
Is there any other better option / or better tool

Answer (score 0):

You may use commercial solutions like [Redline13](https://www.redline13.com) to distribute the users across the agents (i.e. 10 different machines)

You can include the file names associated with the users in a CSV file.
Uses can be uniquely distributed using the split [feature](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2015/02/redline13-support-for-splitting-input-files/) Filename should be picked from the CSV and include in the HTTP Request ${FILE_NAME}. You can upload all the files (to be uploaded) associated with the used.